# Find recurrence relation for the integral $\int_0^1x^ne^{x-1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was required to show that, let $I_n = \int_0^1x^ne^{x-1}dx$, $I_n = 1-nI_{n-1}$

While all I can show is that $I_n = x^ne^{x-1}-nI_{n-1}$ by using integration by parts and the $x^ne^{x-1}$ seems no where close to $1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Your calculations are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have computed the indefinite integral using integration by parts. But what you have is a definite integral.

You have to evaluate $x^{n}e^{x-1}$ between the limits $0$ and $1$: $x^{n}e^{x-1}|_0^{1}=(1^{n})e^{1-1} -0^{n} e^{0-1}=1-0=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You've forgotten the limits!
$$x^{n}e^{x-1}|_0^{1}=1^ne^{1-1} -0^{n} e^{0-1}=1$$